# Why does the direction of the magnetic potential vector follow the current?

Tags: magnetic-fields, potential, magnetostatics

In Griffith's textbook, it is said that the vector potential $\vec{A}$ usually points in the direction of $\vec{J}$:

[image]

This was also pointed out in class.

However, I don't understand why it should be the case. I know already that there are infinite solutions, and that in my current case, magnetostatics, we choose the  $\vec{A}$ such that $\nabla\cdot \vec{A}=0$. This leads to $\vec{A}= \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int_{V}  \frac{\vec{J}}{R}dV$ if our source is finite.

So, how does it follow that the direction is usually that of current? I only see it if the direction were constant.

Comment: Note Griffith's italicized emphasis on *ordinarily* but even that should be understood as sufficiently near the current that is its source, $d\vec{A}= \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi} \frac{\vec{J}}{R}dV$.